# How can I enable Infinity Fabric for Ryzen 2700x?

Tags: windows-10, amd-ryzen

I read that AMD’s Infinity Fabric can boost overall speed, but I’m wondering if this is a feature I need to enable in BIOS or if it’s enabled automatically? I’ve already set my RAM for its highest advertised speed, 3200 MHz, by using DOCP.

Comment: Infinity Fabric has to do with communication between the CPU and GPU.

Comment: It's part of the CPU. https://www.reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/601828/how_the_windows_high_performance_mode_is_limiting/

Answer (score 0):

Infinity Fabric is a type of link (specific to AMD Ryzen CPU's at the moment) that links your CPU cores together. You can't enable or disable it because your Ryzen CPU basically needs it to work.